# Loading a page from hash on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hash

So I wrote this piece of JavaScript using the JQuery library. Its functionality is to have the pages load inside of a `div` instead of an entire page (to make modifying the layout way easier).

I've made it so it successfully saves the 'file URL' in the hash and I've made it so it loads correctly, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to go to that page.

When I try to go to a page with the hash in the name (so for example refreshing a page, or going through a link/URL) it replicates itself (I think) two times inside each other. You can see it happening live at **[overeten.be](http://overeten.be)** and then try to refresh a random page ***except*** the main one.

Could someone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('._body').load("pages/default.html");

    var locationhash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');

    if ((locationhash=='pages/default.html')||(locationhash=='')){
        console.log("no page, "+locationhash);
    } else{
        $('._body').load(window.location.hash);
        console.log(locationhash);
    }
    $('.menubundle a,  footer a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('._body').fadeOut(1000,function(){
            document.location.hash = page;
            $('._body').load(page).fadeIn(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
$('._body').load(window.location.hash);
```

If you inspect window.location.hash, you get this:

```
window.location.hash
"#pages/over_eten/feit.html"
```

That URL points to the current page. What you really want is this:

```
window.location.hash.slice(1)  // Skip the first character
"pages/over_eten/feit.html"
```

On a side note, it seems weird to me that you have two calls to $('._body').load(). The first one seems like it belongs right above console.log('No page...') instead.

Comment: Sadly, that's not the problem.. I was aware that that was a thing, so I added this line;   `var locationhash = window.location.hash.replace('#','');` which replaces the first '#' with nothing (effectively removing it). Furthermore, the two `.load` functions are to make the default page load first, and then the one requested, but I'll move it because it's probably better when the question's been answered to avoid confusion. Thanks anyway for the effort :) EDIT: Whoops, now I see what you ment. I wrote the `window.location.hash` instead of the `locationhash` variable. It's solved, thanks!